# Remove Blank Space from page viewer in UniversalImageLoader

Tags: android, android-layout, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Loader v 1.9.1 .
I am getting blank space at the start and end of image(horizontally).Cant figure out how to get imageview occupy full width of screen.
could this be an issue with images?

MY code Snippets are:

**ac_image_pager.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
             android:id="@+id/pager"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="200dp"  
         />
```

**item_pager_image.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**ImagePagerActivity.java**

Following init configs for pageviewer

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
            .build();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @keshav  the images are here ...
http://i.stack.imgur.com/LHhoX.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/uT75a.png
I dont have enough reputation to add images directly here..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you've specified the ImageView's width to `match_parent`, the height is fixed to 200dp. This means if the image ratio is restricted to the height in respect to its container, the image will be horizontally padded to maintain the aspect ratio.

There are different ways to solve your problem:

- Set the ImageView's scaleType to `fitXY` to allow the image to stretch regardless of its aspect ratio.
- Set the ImageView's height to `wrap_content` to allow the height to be determined dynamically. Beware that the ViewPager's height should cope with this, for instance by being set to `match_parent`.
- Allow [pages of the ViewPager to overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15006910/154306).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for image

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
```