# ImageView image not appearing in ViewGroup but texView working awesome

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Question may look like [Can ViewPager have multiple views in per page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468581/can-viewpager-have-multiple-views-in-per-page)

I am looking for Content swipe in android. found an example [here](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/)
But didn't got how to implement View pager in my app. Then i found a good example [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468581/android-can-view-pager-have-multiple-views-in-per-page/12286698#answer-15006910), and its working awesome.

**Now i want to set dynamic content to slides**

I have tried it but Text is showing but image not i want to show many content in slide.

Adapter class:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


        Context context;

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {




            TextView view = new TextView(PagerActivity.this);
            view.setText("Item "+position);
            view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, position * 50, position * 10, position * 50));

            container.addView(view);
            return view;


            //not working code
            /*ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding = 10;
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            container.addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;*/
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View)object);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view == object);
        }
    }
```

Main XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.pagercontainer.PagerContainer
        android:id="@+id/pager_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CCC">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </com.example.pagercontainer.PagerContainer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**How can i set Dynamic layout for each Page in ViewPager???**

Thanks for taking look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User **[Inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/Inflater.html)**

try this code:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


    TextView des;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider, container,
            false);
    des = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slider_des);
    des.setText(description[position]);

     AQuery aq = new AQuery(itemView);
     aq.id(R.id.imageView1).image(image1[position], true, true, 0, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN, AQuery.RATIO_PRESERVE);

     ((ViewPager) container).removeView(itemView);



    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}
```

---

Or use this library

## [Android-ViewPagerIndicator Example](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: awesome library i am using it now :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should return container inspite of imageview.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = 10;
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        container.addView(imageView, 0);
        return container;
```

Comment: I got it. i replace my code ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context); to ImageView imageView = new ImageView(PagerActivity.this);. But its working i want to add both text and image.

Comment: First create linear layout and then add both in layout and then add layout in container .