# Slide to next element in scrollview android

Tags: android

I have a horizontalscrollview which has some images inside it. Something like this:
[image]

I want that when I swipe my finger on the scrollview, next image should come up directly in the middle and use can slide through all the images that way. Something like a cover art in music applications.

How can I edit my horizontalscrollview to add this functionality?

I know there is flipperview in android. But I want it to look like a scrollview with other images visible along the side

Comment: Have you thought about a `ViewPager`, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468581/can-viewpager-have-multiple-views-in-per-page ?