# How to make Queue like view in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view, android-progressbar

I want to make a view that is like Queue of images. see below image for reference.

[image]

It should work as stated below.

1. Grey image will show batch with all details.
2. The blue Images shows time slots and the whole view will slide with passing time.
3. Red line will show the current time.
4. Progress(Green Part) indicates the portion of Grey image that is processed
5. The Whole view can slide back and fro to show processed batches and upcoming batches.

I want to know what approach should I use. **I don't want code just strategy to make a view like above**. open for any comments.

Comment: Use a viewpager, with a page of image.

Comment: what about progressbar.

Comment: this can be done by `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: @ELITE I haven't used viewflipper, can you provide any links for the usage.

Comment: `ViewFlipper` is same as `ViewPager`, you can show progress by adding `ProgressBar` and `ViewFlipper` in `FrameLayout`.

Comment: You just need nested layouts (LinearLayout, FrameLayout ..etc). Just you want to spend some time to design your layout. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12286698/4795214